# Constructing a named list without having to type each object's name twice

Tags: r, list

In interactive use, I occasionally need to bundle a largish set of
objects together in a list. To get a list in which the elements keep
their original names, I am forced to write something like
`list(Object1=Object1, Object2=Object2, ..... , Object25=Object25)`.

Is there some straightforward way to place a set of named objects in a list, such that they 'keep' their names, without having to type `nameXXX=nameXXX` for each one?

```
cars <- mtcars[1:2,1:2]
vowels <- c("a","e","i","o","u")
consonants <- setdiff(letters, vowels)

## I'd like to get this result...
list(consonants=consonants, vowels=vowels, cars=cars)
## $consonants
##  [1] "b" "c" "d" "f" "g" "h" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t" "v" "w" "x"
## [20] "y" "z"
##
## $vowels
## [1] "a" "e" "i" "o" "u"
##
## $cars
##               mpg cyl
## Mazda RX4      21   6
## Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6

## ... but by doing something more like
f(consonants, vowels, cars)
```

Comment: Thanks, @BenBolker -- I'd accept your answer if I could.

Answer (score 19):

You can get the same structure with

```
mget(c("vowels", "consonants", "cars"))
```

but you do have to do have to quote the variable names which isn't super sexy.

Comment: This modification allows unquoted names: `mget(sapply(expression(vowels, consonants, cars), paste))`

Comment: Interesting. I'm kind of surprised `paste` works like that. I would have expected a `deparse`.

Answer (score 11):

Here's what I used most recently.

It would be nice, though, if there were something more succinct (or something built into base R or a decent package), so please feel free to add other/better answers.

```
LIST <- function(...) {
    nms <- sapply(as.list(substitute(list(...))), deparse)[-1]
    setNames(list(...), nms)
}

LIST(vowels, consonants, cars)
# $vowels
# [1] "a" "e" "i" "o" "u"
# 
# $consonants
#  [1] "b" "c" "d" "f" "g" "h" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t" "v" "w" "x"
# [20] "y" "z"
# 
# $cars
#               mpg cyl
# Mazda RX4      21   6
# Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
namedList  <-  function(...){
    out  <-  list(...)
    for(i in seq(length(out)))
        names(out)[i]  <-  as.character(sys.call()[[i+1]])
    out
}

foo = 1
bar = 'Hello world'
namedList(foo,bar)

#> $foo
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $bar
#> [1] "Hello world"
```